# Como reemplazar arreglos bidimensionales con diccionarios/listas/tuplas etc

Tags: c#, array, matrices, diccionarios

Hola a todos mi caso es el siguiente: 
-Tengo una variable que es un arreglo bidimensional de una clase: 
una pertenece a la familia de productos

```
private Prodx[,] productox;
```

esta está declarada como variables globales. En el constructor de la clase se llenan del siguiente modo:

```
productox= new Prodx[10, 50];
```

Como pueden observar, se les está asignando un tamaño ya definido (no dinámico).

Después en otra parte del código, a esa matriz se le asigna un valor de la siguiente manera:

```
Prodx[indicex, indicey] = newProducto;
```

Lo que se me está pidiendo es cambiar toda esta parte del código para pasarla a listas, diccionarios o tuplas... 
El problema esta que al no ser dinámico todo ese espacio no ocupado se queda ahí nada más en nulo... alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Los arrays y matrices en c# son dinámicas, debido a que, no usa memoria estática. Básicamente lo que pides, es alguna estructura de datos en la cual no tengas que colocar el tamaño. Una opción es usar un `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por algún motivo que no alcanzo a entender, tus productos están almacenados en coordenadas, las cuáles se señalan con `indicex` e `indicey`. Puedes tener un diccionario cuya clave sea las coordenadas y cuyo valor sea le producto:

```
class Coordenada
{
    public int indicex { get; set; }
    public int indicey { get; set; }
}

var productos = new Dictionary<Coordenada, Prodx>();
```

Puedes usarlo [así](https://tio.run/##pZNBS8MwFMfPzad4DA8dbMVNPdUNZIIHFQRBD@IhJs8a6JKRpHOl9LPX17qtY1Zh7pBA0t/79f3hRbihMBarKnNKJ/CYO4/zmO2eoplJUxReGe2iG9RolYgZEyl3DmbGWImaS84KFiyyt1QJUNrTkkrgCgpI0Mfg6q3sIPI9otyYH6yRq32p/INOLJ/XvPPcE780RN9zpUPnLaV5eQVuE9dnATHBkltY0B8y4Y2DCWj8hGvVhOQ2v2xjDb4bmYb9mMq2JdGVlGFd1JLFJvIETgfbdHQoB42@8RTUVH31b9vop210mG60qxt36Y7wnXX6DhOOd4Xn3cIjjBe/GBslI@k7PQguPiCshwRTnKP2hgTtwNAQBcGM3oNJMXq2yuOd0hie9IoNHt1iHq0bKIdd13kJwym0X554mmGkZNmrk9FoV9UX):

```
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 0, indicey = 0}, new Prodx());
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 0, indicey = 1}, new Prodx());
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 1, indicey = 2}, new Prodx());
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 1, indicey = 3}, new Prodx());
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 2, indicey = 4}, new Prodx());
productos.Add(new Coordenada{indicex = 2, indicey = 5}, new Prodx());
```

Comment: Me parece que esto es exactamente lo que buscaba... algo así se me había ocurrido pero no lograba plasmar la idea del todo... muchas gracias y por el momento estoy trabajando en otra cosa pero estoy casi seguro que tu respuesta es bien acertada, gracias!

Comment: En efecto están en coordenadas porque se trata de un menú tipo matriz bidimensional y los productos se cargan dinámicamente creando la matriz, no sé si me explico

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una lista declarandola de esta forma:

```
 List<Prodx> prodxes = new List<Prodx>();

 prodxes.Add(new Prodx("nombre", "precio"));
```

y cuando usas private, la variable no es global es privada y accesible unicamente desde la clase en que la usas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una lista que contenga listas de Prodx de esta manera:

```
List<List<Prodx>> productox = new List<List<Prodx>>();
```

Agregar valores de esta forma:

```
productox.Add(new List<Prodx>());
productox[0].Add(new Prodx { Prop1 = "value", Prop2 = "value"});
productox[0].Add(new Prodx());
```

O esta:

```
List<Prodx> temp = new List<Prodx>();
temp.Add(new Prodx { Prop1 = "value", Prop2 = "value"});
temp.Add(new Prodx());

productox.Add(temp);
```

Y obtener los valores así:

```
Prodx prodx = productox[0][1];
```